# Provisional + いい + ん + だろ

Tags: grammar, meaning

ここ は… どう 言えば いい ん だろ。

I think the ん here is the abbreviated の resulting in のだろ.

I'm not sure how to connect it with the provisional form どう 言えば いい.

If the latter means: *It will be good if I somehow say...*, then would the former modify the *will* to *would*?

The result being: *It **would** be good if I somehow **said** (as in named this place).*

Is this interpretation correct? I was trying to translate it around いいん being a noun. It made some sense due to the overall context, but felt like I'm forcing the meaning. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have misinterpreted the word どう.

You translate it as *somehow*, but its meaning is *how* or *in what way*.

The part 言えばいい is good, so the literal interpretation of どう言えばいい is *It would be good if in what way I say.* So its meaning is *how I should say*.

Next, yes, ん is の. The second point is that だろ is an abbreviation of [だろう](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86), whose meaning is *I wonder* here.

So, どう言えばいいんだろ translates to *I wonder how I should say.* In this case, however, *I wonder **what** I should say* is actually closer to its nuance.